# How to make msbuild output .pdb file

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, .net-core

I use .net core in linux, and `dotnet build(same with msbuild)` output is like:

```
roroco@roroco ~/Downloads/test/cs/create-nuget-dep-and-use-it/Dep $ FrameworkPathOverride=/usr/lib/mono/4.5/ dotnet build /p:DebugType=full
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.409.57025 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Dep -> /home/roroco/Downloads/test/cs/create-nuget-dep-and-use-it/Dep/Dep/bin/Debug/Dep.dll

Build succeeded.
```

It only generate dll file, I hope it generate .pdb file, how should i do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm wrong, msbuild will generate `.pdb` file default but the msbuild output will not show it